# MySQL - Count the number of occurrences according to pattern in a VARCHAR field?

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
> URL          
> ------------------------------------------------ 
> http://www.example.com 
> http://www.example.com/one
> http://www.example.com/one/two/abc.txt 
> http://www.example.com/three/four
> http://www.example.com/five/six/seven/def.txt
```

I wonder if I can use a single SQL query which could count the occurrences of the URL pattern and output the result as below:

```
> URL PATTERN                                   |   COUNT
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
> http://www.example.com/                       |     5
> http://www.example.com/one/                   |     2
> http://www.example.com/one/two/               |     1 
> http://www.example.com/three/                 |     1
> http://www.example.com/three/four/            |     1
> http://www.example.com/five/                  |     1
> http://www.example.com/five/six/              |     1
> http://www.example.com/five/six/seven/        |     1
```

Is it possible to write it in SQL (MySQL)?

Thanks.

Comment: yes, you can using `like %varchar%`

Comment: Would you mind show me the sql? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for example :

```
update table_b set 
    count = (select count(url) 
    from table_a where url like "http://www.example.com/%") 
    where url_pattern = "http://www.example.com/"
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm afraid this one could only update the count with url_pattern = "http://www.example.com/".  What I really want is a query which can generate a result looks like the 2nd table above.

Comment: and where you get one, two, three, and so on value? automatically generate? or in another table?

Comment: I only have the table with URL, i.e. table 1. I have no idea the "one", "two", "three", etc would be in the URL table.

Comment: then you cannot achive it by using only sql

Comment: ic. Any workaround like using temp working table in order to achieve this?